# Embedded C++ with ARM Gcc, removing of unnecessary STL functions

Tags: stl, linker, arm

I'm programming a embedded system with C++ and the STL library. 
As the memory is getting low, I did some memory dumps to see where is all the memory lost. In the symbol dump (`arm-none-eabi-objdump -t`), I found a lot of items from the libstdcc++ library. There are for example 348 items from the 
`moneypunct` class, also as I never used this class nor I have any text output, so I don't need any localization or text formatting classes. 
Is there a way to stip all of those items from the STL library?

The compiler is the gnu arm embedded gcc, (Gnu Tools for ARM Embedde Processors 6-2017-q1-update, gcc version 6.3.1)

I already used the standard arm gcc optimizations, so for example `-Wl,--gcc-sections`, `--specs=nano.sepcs`, functions and data sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok just solved it,

also I did not use any streams, the iostream library included a lot of overhead. removing all

```
#include <iostream>
```

includes saved 120kbyte of flash